# GridView removing row too soon

Tags: android

I'm using a GridView that fills the whole of my main activity. To make it look nicer I'm using a transparent action bar. I'm using these values on my grid view so that the content doesn't start in the action bar but still scrolls through it:

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

The only problem is once the bottom of the row enters the action bar it disappears. I'm assuming because Android thinks it is no longer visible so it's safe to remove.

I'd like a way for it to not disappear, even past the status bar as I'll probably make that transparent on KitKat too. Either a different approach or a simple solution would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a problem with the TwoWayGridView library I was using (https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). Switched back to a normal GridView and it works fine.